# Troubleshooting spring devtools

Tags: spring, spring-boot-devtools

I'm having trouble with spring devtools. it's not picking up any changes to class files. I've confirmed as much as I can in terms of configuration and files actually being changed.

What are my options in terms of getting additional information (e.g. increasing logging, getting what paths are monitored, logging the last timestamps seen, whether it's active at all, etc.)?

EDIT: A few more notes, the project is gradle + kotlin, command line only. I'm running `gradle bootRun` in one terminal and `gradle compileKotlin` in another. I confirmed that compilation happens and that classes in `build/classes` are being updated (looking at the timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

As much I know dev-tool behaves differently in Eclipse and Intellij . In Eclipse .class gets created as soon as u save , so it will be reflected. It does not happen in IntelliJ. To achieve this in IntelliJ u have to use macro of saving and compiling.

Comment: Thanks, I just added a couple of notes to the question - I'm not using an IDE.